# How to minimize generated urls in wicket?

Tags: java, wicket

For example, there is a table on the page. The table is in the tab. The tab is in the panel and so on. The result is a hierarchy of dozens of components. In the table there is the column, and in the column there is some kind of component with a link, for example column sorter.

As a result, this link has very large URL, something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/mypage?5-1.-body-centerPanel-files-roll_down-panel-files-panel-repeater-3-item-form-table-topToolbars-toolbars-2-headers-2-header-orderByLink&id=94819
```

In fact the URL can reach several hundred characters.

Is there a way to minify this URL to a reasonable size?

I would like to achieve a URL like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/mypage?sdsi93rh&id=94819
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a custom IRequestMapper that wraps the default root request mapper. You can use [HttpsMapper](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/master/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/protocol/https/HttpsMapper.java) for inspiration.

To set it up:

```
setRootRequestMapper(new UrlShorteningMapper(getRootRequestMapper()));
```

The idea is to shorten the request url + query string in #mapRequest() method and to de-shorten it in #mapHandler().

There are many articles in the web how to do url shortening. Here is [one](https://dzone.com/articles/url-shortener-service-42-lines)